# Running axio request on the server in test environment

Tags: node.js, axios, chai, chai-http

I have two different express servers running on localhost on different ports on my laptop. One of them is making a request to the other one.

I am trying to test server A using chai-http, but the subsequent request from server A to server B results in a `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3020`.

The server A request to server B:

```
try {
    await axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: `${process.env.userapi}/invite`,
      data: { user: { email } },
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    throw e;
  }
}
```

The server B
    // Bootstrap routes
    require('./config/passport')(passport);
    require('./config/express')(app, passport);
    require('./config/routes')(app, passport);

```
mongoose.connection.on('error', connect);
mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', connect);
mongoose.connection.once('open', listen);

function listen() {
  // if (app.get('env') === 'test') return;
  if (!module.parent) app.listen(port);
  console.log('Express app started on port ' + port);
}

...

app.post('/invite', invitationCtrl);
```

Server B config

```
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.setHeader(
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
      'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, appid'
    );
    res.setHeader(
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
      'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS'
    );
    if (req.method == 'OPTIONS') {
      res.status(200).end();
    } else {
      next();
    }
```

The `/invite` route seems to be working when testing it using postman but not with chai. I am suspecting the axios call, but I don't know where to look